# how to check OR condition using if statement in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have command list which will be executed on several server. There is 2 specific command which gets the logs from system and I need to parse these 2 log files to get only required data, which is currently working from below code. but am not able figure out how to check if command executed is that of those 2 log command if so, proceed with rest of the logic, if not then just skip the next few lines. I am not able to find how can we use if statement in batch script which can have OR condition as well.

although am using for loop currently in which am able to check only one command but not both

command list file content :
ipconfig
sys1/log1
Fdisk
map1/log1

from the above command, I would like to check if either of the command ie, sys1/log1 or map1/log1 then perform below logic

code :

Version:1.0

```
    for /f %%i in ('findstr /li /c:"sys1/log1" /c:"ipconfig" !MyLog!') do (
    set "wanted=WARNING MINOR MAJOR"
    echo echo severity  date        time    Description > !MyLog!_out.log
     (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('type !MyLog!^|findstr "severity= date= time= description="') do (
      if "%%a"=="    severity" echo\
    REM this is four SPACES above before severity
      <nul set /p "=%%b   "
     REM above there is a SPACE and a TAB after %%b 
     )
    echo/
     )  >>!MyLog!_out.log
     type !MyLog!_out.log | findstr /b "severity %wanted%" > !MyLog!_out.log
 )
```

Version:1.1

```
1       for /f %%i in ('findstr /li /c:"sys1/log1" /c:"ipconfig" !MyLog!') do 2(
3       set "wanted=WARNING MINOR MAJOR"
4       echo echo severity  date        time    Description > !MyLog!_out.log
5        (
6        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('type !MyLog!^|findstr "severity= date= time= description="') do (
7          if "%%a"=="    severity" echo\
8       REM this is four SPACES above before severity
9          <nul set /p "=%%b   "
10         REM above there is a SPACE and a TAB after %%b 
11       )
12        echo/
13       )  >>!MyLog!_out.log
14   for %%a in (!MyLog!) do (
15    echo %%a | find /n /i !wanted! >> !MyLog!_out.log
16    echo %%a
17  )
18     )
```

Any idea/suggestion/help please.

MyLog.log output :

```
echo severity  date        time    Description 

MINOR 01/04/2015   08:56   Maintenance note: App  logs cleared through sys tool
WARNING 02/22/2015   19:59   POST Error: Caching will be enabled once Super-Cap has been charged. No action is required.   
WARNING 03/13/2015   14:34   POST Error:  Caching will be enabled once Super-Cap has been charged. No action is required.   
MAJOR 10/13/2015   15:03   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 1)   
MAJOR 01/13/2016   13:03   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 0)   
MAJOR 01/21/2016   02:39   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 0)   
MAJOR 06/09/2016   01:01   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 0)
```

Comment: Just change your `findstr` command to `findstr /li /c:"ipconfig sys1/log1" /c:"fdisk map1/log1" !MyLog!`.  That will match lines containing either string, effectively satisfying your OR condition.

Comment: Thanks rojo. your suggestion did the trick for checking either commands. now how do I get only the required logs in the final output file. I have set the Wanted variable but don't know how to filter out the wanted lines from output file. Can you please suggestion. I did try adding below line after )!MyLog!_out.log but got nothing.  type !MyLog!_out.log | findstr /b "severity %wanted%" > !MyLog!_out.log

Answer (score 0):

Once you implemented *rojo*'s suggestion, incorporate this script instead of yours inner loop inside the outer FOR loop, and post here if any issues:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
-------------------------------------

rem Inside your outer FOR loop, add this construct

set "wanted=WARNING MINOR MAJOR"
for %%a in ("%wanted%") do (
    for %%b in (!MyLog!) do (
        echo %%b | find /n /i %%a >nul >> !MyLog!_out.log
        echo %%a %%b))
```

Comment: Thanks Sambul35. I did add your for loop code after first for loop. I get some find command error ie, "FIND: Parameter format not correct" and even !MyLog!.out.log file gets created with just header info.

Comment: @Prime Pls edit your original question. Add at its bottom current version of your script, so I can read it. You can remove it later. Also, save and run my above updated script from open Cmd window, and post the output portion here in a comment. I need to see echo lines content, including the lines with content you want to find.

Comment: I have update the original post and added version1.0 (which is very first version) and version1.1 (in which I have made the changes as you said) please let me know if this this correct. I ran the version1.1 with pause command after "echo %%a" and I can see the full filename as o/p

Comment: @Prime You have extra ) before echo/ now. Also, I don't see, where you implemented rojo's code.

Comment: I have implemented rojo's code in very first for loop (line no 1) and about the extra ), there is open ( for this. ie, line 5 and 11

Comment: @Prime But roj's suggestion was `findstr /li /c:"ipconfig sys1/log1" /c:"fdisk map1/log1" !MyLog!`. Also, your script looks messed up, what text do you manage to echo now into `!MyLog!_out.log`? Why did you place several functions inside ( ) echo section, despite such section just echos strings to file?

Comment: I did implement rojo's code except I kept only 2 commands (log1 commands) to check in the for loop even there are other commands present(like ipconfig, fdisk - for this I don't need to parse the log to get the required result). I didn't get about last quesiton ie, why I placed several functions inside () echo section ? can you please suggestion which line no I need to comment/remove. so I can try..

Comment: Pls post a large enough printout of MyLog.log in your above question as an example. Its hard to figure out from your script, what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Prime I updated the answer code based on your log. Try to incorporate it into your script. Still not sure, what you're trying to accomplish with the 2nd FOR section with _severity_ string, enclosed in ( )?